# SharePoint Alternate Mappings. Code behind pulling wrong zone

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have some code in a SharePoint page that is attempting to get the provider information for the currently used Web App and Zone.

This code finds the zone name correctly:

```
SPWebApplication app = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;
SPAlternateUrl u = app.AlternateUrls[Request.Url];
SPUrlZone zone = u.UrlZone;
```

The zone comes back "Custom" or "Default", depending on which URL/Server is used.

Next, I try to get the IIS Settings for that zone using the code below:

```
SPIisSettings settings = app.IisSettings[zone];
```

I get an exception when testing the "Custom" site/URL (AAM). It seems that no matter what URL/Server I access the site from, app.IisSettings[] only contains a "key" for "Default".

What am I missing?

Shayne

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
SPWebApplication iisApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(Request.Url);
SPIisSettings settings = iisApp.IisSettings[zone];
```

To get the IisSettings for a different zone. As the SPContext might be returning you the Default IIS web app.

Comment: Good idea, but it still doesn't work. Even with the code above, the only "zone" returned from the other IIS is still just "Default"....